# API: Issue with exact match in deep queries

Tags: rally

I'm querying for test results which are associated with any test set that has a particular tag.

However, this query does not work:

(TestSet.Tags.Name = "foo")

What does work is:

(TestSet.Tags.Name contains "foo")

I would think the first query should work if the second one returns matches with the tag "foo".  I presume this is a bug?

I can get around this problem by using the second query, but of course the problem is that this can match a tag named "foo2" as well, so my query can have extra results (potentially many more) and I have to filter them out.  Additionally, now I need to have my query fetch the "Tags" as well, so every result I get back is larger because of it.

Comment: Do you mean TestCase.Tags ...? I don't think you can Tag TestSets.

Comment: You can tag test sets-- its just not very visible.  We use it all the time to organize our test sets.  Create a custom grid for TestSets and show the "Tags" column.

Comment: Interesting, learn something new every day! I'll experiment to see if I can reproduce this behavior.

Comment: I'm going to guess that this behavior occurs in other places where you are querying against multiple child objects (in this case Tag Names connected to a test set).  I'll bet the algorithm collects all the members and joins them into one field for searching, thus it would work for "contains" but not =.  Still a bug non-the-less...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as user1195996 suggested this feels like a bug.  Your same queries work as expected against defect or user stories.  Please work with Rally Support on this issue so we can work to correct it.

Comment: Thanks-- I opened a defect with Rally support